# Append to default value of a list in emacs-lisp: specifically, dotspacemacs-configuration-layers

Tags: emacs, append, spacemacs

## Goal

I wish to further extend modularity of my `spacemacs` configuration by referencing files `user-config.org` and `user-layers.org`

### Template

I have achieved the former by adding the following to my dotspacemacs/user-config:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name
                        "user-config.org" dotspacemacs-directory)))
```

I can safely experiment with, clone-sync, `org`anize, version-control `user-config.org`

### Problem

Now,
dotspacemacs/user-layers is a variable (default-)set in a function in the following manner:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
   dotspacemacs-distribution 'spacemacs  ;; not relevant
   ;;
   ;; many such default variable-value lines in between, skipped.
   ;;
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ;;
     ;; many layers auto-added/managed by spacemacs
     ;;
     git
     (python :variables python-backend 'lsp
           python-lsp-server 'pyright
           ;; other such python configurations
           python-formatter 'yapf))
   ;; other such default varialbe-value declarations
  )
)
```

### Attempt

I tried adding a similar inheretance (as with `user-config`) at the end of the `setq-default` in the following manner,

- N.B. `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` cannot be modified outside the function `dotspacemacs/layers`, hence, reference to the file has to be called within that function.

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  (setq-default
    dotspacemacs-distribution 'spacemacs
    ;;
    ;; many such default variable-value lines in between, skipped.
    ;;
    dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
    '(
    ;; whatever spacemacs wants to auto-add
    )
    ;; other such default variable-value declarations
  )
  (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name
    "user-layers.org" dotspacemacs-directory))
)
```

—such that `user-layers.org` is of the following form:

#### Referenced `org-mode` file:

- dotspacemacs layers

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

```lisp
(append dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
  '(
    ;;
    ;; Other layers managed by the user
    ;;
    git
    (python :variables python-backend 'lsp
            python-lsp-server 'pyright
            ;; other such python configurations
            python-formatter 'yapf)))
```

#+END_SRC

### Failure

However, `append` does not appear to add elements to the `seq-default` value.
I guess it is appending to the variable's local `setq` value.
(I may be wrong at this, as lisp isn't my motherbored tongue, python is.)

## Question:

Is there a way to extend the **default** value of a list in emacs-lisp by adding elements from another list?

### clarification:

—such that after addition, the default value of the list contains the newly added elements.

Comment: Given [This Important Note](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#important-note), it appears wiser to separately tangle and (load user-layers.el).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   (append (default-value 'dotspacemacs-configuration-layers)
           '(git ...)))
```

---

Note that `append` doesn't modify the original list - it creates a new list with the extra values added. To add values to a list contained in a variable you need to assign back the new list:

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq x (list 1 2 3))
(1 2 3)

ELISP> (setq y (list 4 5 6))
(4 5 6)

ELISP> (append x y)
(1 2 3 4 5 6)

ELISP> x
(1 2 3)

ELISP> (setq x (append x y))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)

ELISP> x
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: ... or you can use `(add-to-list 'some-list new-element)`. An optional third argument determines if the new element is added to the beginning or the end of the list. Do `C-h f add-to-list` for details.